# strdup and memory leaking

Tags: c, memory-leaks, strdup

Does strdup allocate another memory zone and create another pointer every time?

For example: does the following code result in a memory leak?

```
void x(char** d, char* s){
    *d = strdup(s);
}

int main(){
    char* test = NULL;
    x(&test, "abcd");
    x(&test, "etc");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this leaks memory.

Comment: How could it work if it didn't allocate more memory? Where would it put all the duplicates?

Comment: @Barmar The program takes no inputs and produces no outputs, so how it could work without allocating memory could be like this `int main() { return 0; }`. A compiler is permitted to do this optimization, even.

Comment: @Kaz I meant "how could strdup work in any other way?"

Comment: You're right Barman. But is there any function that I could use to replace the second call of x() ? Without doing, myself, the reallocation and after that the copy of the new string to the same pointer? Basically, what I'm asking is if there is a function like strdup but with realloc instead of malloc

Comment: ^ I added that to the answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, the program leaks memory because it allocates objects and then loses references to them.

The first time this happens is in the line:

```
 x(&test, "etc");
```

The variable `test` holds the one and only copy of a pointer that was allocated in a previous call to `x`. The new call to `x` overwrites that pointer. At that point, the pointer leaks.

This is what it means to leak memory: **to lose all references to an existing dynamically allocated piece of storage**.<sup>*</sup>

The second leak occurs when the `main` function returns. At that point, the `test` variable is destroyed, and that variable holds the one and only copy of a pointer to a duplicate of the `"etc"` string.

Sometimes in C programs, we sometimes not care about leaks of this second type: memory that is not freed when the program terminates, but that is not allocated over and over again in a loop (so it doesn't cause a runaway memory growth problem).

If the program is ever integrated into another program (for instance as a shared library) where the original `main` function becomes a startup function that could be invoked repeatedly in the same program environment, both the leaks will turn into problems.

The POSIX `strdup` function behaves similarly to this:

```
char *strdup(const char *orig)
{
   size_t bytes = strlen(orig) + 1;
   char *copy = malloc(bytes);
   if (copy != 0)
     memcpy(copy, orig, bytes);
   return copy;
}
```

Yes; it allocates new storage each time.

If you have a garbage collector (such as Boehm) in your C image, then it's possible that the leaked storage is recycled, and so `strdup` is able to re-use the same memory for the second allocation. (However, a garbage collector is not going to kick in after just one allocation, unless it is operated in a stress-test mode for flushing out bugs.)

Now if you want to actually reuse the memory with realloc, then you can change your `x` function along these lines:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void *strealloc(char *origptr, char *strdata)
{
    size_t nbytes = strlen(strdata) + 1;
    char *newptr = (char *) realloc(origptr, nbytes); /* cast needed for C++ */
    if (newptr)
      memcpy(newptr, strdata, nbytes);
    return newptr;
}
```

(By the way, external names starting with `str` are in an ISO C reserved namespace, but `strealloc` is too nice a name to refuse.)

Note that the interface is different. We do not pass in a pointer-to-pointer, but instead present a `realloc`-like interface. The caller can check the return value for null to detect an allocation error, without having the pointer inconveniently overwritten with null in that case.

The `main` function now looks like:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *test = strealloc(NULL, "abcd");
    test = strealloc(test, "etc");
    free(test);
    return 0;
}
```

Like before, there is no error checking. If the first `strealloc` were to fail, `test` is then null. That doesn't since it gets overwritten anyway, and the first argument of `strealloc` may be null.

Only one `free` is needed to plug the memory leak.

---

* It's possible to have a semantic memory leak with objects that the program hasn't lost a reference to. For instance, suppose that a program keeps adding information to a list which is never used for any purpose and just keeps growing.

Comment: Thanks for your excelent answer, I learned alot from it! :) I understand that this is the best implementation and I see why, but if I was forced to call the function as strealloc (&test, "etc"),how should I implement it in this case? I'm guessing that I should create a new pointer inside the function, allocate memory for it and after copying the string, if everything went well, only then I would (thus not affect origptr in any way if the memory allocation went wrong) do something like *origptr = newptr (and before this free(*origptr). Please let me know if any of this makes sense.

Comment: Whether to use `&test` and update the pointer in place or whether to return the new value is just an interface design detail. If a memory allocation error occurs, you 1) need to know and 2) perhaps don't want to lose the old pointer. So the value-returning interface is better in this regard.  It doesn't really change the implementation; we can still use `realloc` if the function is called as `strealloc(&test, "etc")`.  It might be a good idea to also return an `int` value in this case: `1` if it works, `0` if it fails.

Comment: Is this a good implementation in this case?

    void *strealloc(char **origptr, char *strdata)
    {
        size_t nbytes = strlen(strdata) + 1;
        char *newptr = malloc(nbytes);
        if (newptr != NULL)
        {
            memcpy(newptr, strdata, nbytes);
            free(*origptr);
            *origptr = newptr;
        }
        return newptr;
    }

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it allocates memory and leaks if you don't free it. From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup):

> The **strdup()** function returns a pointer to a new string which is a duplicate of the string s. Memory for the new string is obtained with [malloc(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc), and can be freed with [free(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free).

`new_s = strdup(s)` is essentially equivalent to:

```
new_s = malloc(strlen(s)+1);
strcpy(new_s, s);
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following definition for `strdup`:

```
#include <string.h>
char *strdup(const char *string);
```

> `strdup` reserves storage space for a copy of `string` by calling `malloc`. The string argument to this function is expected to contain a `null` character (`\0`) marking the end of the string. Remember to free the storage reserved with the call to `strdup`.

You must `free` the string yourself.